# cannot click on a react panel element using Cypres

Tags: reactjs, cypress

No matter what I try I cannot seem to be able to click on a React panel using cypress.  I am at my wits end. i attached the html that i am trying to click on(all clubs).

[image: HTML under test]

It appears that Cypress somehow on the click doesnt apply an open class to the results.

I have tried:
        `cy.get('div.flg-search-panel-states-filter ul li').eq(4).then((el) => {`
        `cy.wrap(el).click({force:true});`
        `});`

also `cy.get('div.flg-search-panel-states-filter ul li').contains('All Clubs').click({force:true})`

but nothing seems to work or works some of the time.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: I have posted an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add a bit of wait `cy.wait(2000)`before the Filter popup open/ loads and then try the below code. Let me know if this is working for you ?

```
cy.get('.panel-content > .flg-search-filter-container > .flg-search-panel-states-filter > ul > li').eq(4).contains("All Clubs").click({force:true});
```

Comment: I managed to find a solution to my issue.  The problem was that when you navigate to the page the page loads but I had to wait for a presumably a google map to load in the background.  Once I did that it works.  Thanks for your response

Comment: Good to know that !